# Modifying rich content on home page programmatically

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010

I am provisioning site collections programmatically in SP2010.  The process is working fine but I need to be able to customize some text on the home page that is contained in rich text (not in a web part).  Is there a way to grab that HTML code and modify it from code?  For instance, embedded within the home page, I have a title and a paragraph of text.  I'd like to customize the title based on one of the input values provided from the provisioning request.  Is it possible to do this?  Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can access the content area as follows:

```
PublishingWeb pw = null;
//"web" is your SPWeb, didn't include using statement for your SPSite/SPWeb in this sample
if (PublishingWeb.IsPublishingWeb(web))
{
    pw = PublishingWeb.GetPublishingWeb(web); 
}
//todo: add some handling here for if web is not a publishingWeb
//assuming your home page is the default, if not - get the correct page here
SPFile defaultpage = pw.DefaultPage;
if (!(defaultpage.CheckOutType == SPFile.SPCheckOutType.None))
{
   //programatically creating this stuff, so cancel any unexpected checkouts
   defaultpage.UndoCheckOut();
}
defaultpage.CheckOut();
//Field you want to add HTML in (Alternatively, retreive existing data and modify the HTML)
defaultpage.ListItemAllFields["PublishingPageContent"] = "string of HTML";
defaultpage.ListItemAllFields.Update();
defaultpage.CheckIn("My Comment");
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response.  After some additional digging, I was told that we did not implement publishing so this will not be a viable solution for me.  Sounds like we will be incorporating our change into a new page layout. Grateful for your clear, concise answer, hope that it will eventually help someone else.