# Modify the content of the home page programmatically in SharePoint 2010

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

First of all, I'm pretty new to SharePoint so don't shoot me if this is a noobish question or if I don't provide all the right information at once... :)

I have a team-site in SharePoint with following URL: "http://myServer/Opdracht_Ben/". By going to this URL I'm redirected to following page: "http://myServer/sites/Opdracht_Ben/SitePages/Home.aspx".

In Visual Studio I have a project for this site with a feature. When this site-feature is activated it should change the content of the home-page to some custom tekst and layout (i.e.: HTML). The content is not contained within a web part or the page is not a WikiPage, just text on a page.

I've been looking on MSDN and on several tech-sites and blogs but I have not found anything that could help me further. Does anyone know how I can 'reach' the content of the page and modify/update it?

**PS:**
Here on SO I have found a related question ([**Click for the question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7849605/modifying-rich-content-on-home-page-programmatically)), but the provided solution is for when the web is a "Publishing Web", which is not the case here, so that solution won't do me any good.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found out that the page IS a WikiPage after all. So I managed to change the content with following code:

```
using (var site = new SPSite(ApplicationResources.Url.SiteRoot))
{
    using (var web = site.OpenWeb())
    {
        var page = web.GetFile(ApplicationResources.Url.FullDefaultPageName);
        var item = page.Item;
        item["Wiki Content"] = NewContent(title, text);
        item.Update();
    }
}
```

Maybe this is not the best method, so if anyone has a better and more reliable solution: feel free to correct me! ;)